# Scanf in to array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

This a dot_product function of 2 vectors of the same length.

I don't understand how to build the array because how the machine will know which input goes to which input (for example i want a={1,2,3} but the input of 123 will come a[0]= 123)...

How do I make end of array[index] input and how do I make end of the whole array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXINPUT 100
int dot_product(int v[], int u[], int n)
{
    int result = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < n; i++)
       result += v[i]*u[i];
    return result;
}
 int main(){
int v1[MAXINPUT];
int v2[MAXINPUT];
int count = 0 
int i,print;


printf(" first vector:");
for(i=0;i<MAXINPUT;i++){
  scanf("%d", &v1[i]);
  count +=1;
}
printf(" second vector:");
for(i=0;i<MAXINPUT;i++)
  scanf("%d", &v2[i]);
print = dot_product(v1, v2, count);
printf("v1*v2:%d",print);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you want `a={1,2,3}`, input `1 2 3` instead of `123`.

Comment: `if(1 != scanf("%d", &v1[i])) break;`

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I observe here is with

```
 count +=1;
```

where `count` is an uninitialized automatic local variable, which makes it's initial value indeterminate. Attempt to use that value invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should be initializing `count` to `0`.

That said, here, you're depending on the user to input the second array with *exact* same dimension of that of the first one. In case that does not happen, your program will blow up, as you did not initialize the arrays, again.

Comment: yeah fixed that but still that just a missed i dont understand the eof...

Comment: @eGevol _the eof_ ?? Could you be more explicit ?